# Help with z-index issue with menu in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

Has anyone got any idea why the menu is rendering below the rotating images on this site in IE7: http://new.coffeelatino.co.uk/.

The z-index is much higher for the menu that it is for the rotating images.

Just another reason why IE is so dreadful.

Comment: http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html

Comment: `Just another reason why IE is so dreadful.` - The problem doesn't exist in IE8, so I guess it's one less reason?

Comment: Unrelated note:In ie8; all of the rotating images are visible at once when the page is only partially done loading.  You might want to make all but one of the slideshow images start out with display set to none to prevent this.

Comment: @Andy E: The fact that it doesn't exist in IE8 is no consolation. I still need to fix the issue for versions below 8. It works perfectly in every other browser....and this seems to always be the case.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for the advice. That is the next issue :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

z-index is ignored for elements that are not positioned.  Add "position:relative" to the style of whatever you're trying to apply a z-index to, and that should fix it.

Hint for remaining sane as a web developer:  Write against IE, then test with other browsers.  Most things that work in IE will render correctly in FF and Chrome.  The reverse, as you've noticed, is not true.

Comment: Probably an excellent tip. I always work the other way around. I just with IE would go away :).

Comment: Awesome. Adding position: relative; to the top brown bar resolved the issue.

Comment: I would NOT recommend coding for IE and testing in others! Write against the standards and test in several browsers in parallel. Add hacks to ie later. It's easier to persuade ie to behave with standards code, than getting ie code to work reliably in others...